# Record a macro in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

Is is possible to record a macro in Outlook 2010? From everything I have read, the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatelly, there is no marco recorder for Outlook 2010. You will have to type the macro manually...